# Assets 2.0.5 not indexing

Tags: assets

Just installed Assets 2.0.5 on EE2.5.2.

When I click 'update indexes' I get no loading bars.

I have checked my .htaccess file, which shouldn't interfere:

## EE-supported method for removing index.php

RewriteEngine On
        # Removes index.php
        RewriteCond $1 !.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

```
    # If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing
    # make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark)
```

## EE 404 page for missing pages

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php/404/index

## Simple 404 for missing files

ErrorDocument 404 "File Not Found"

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sr=
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.kontera.com/$1? [R=301]

Comment: Hey,

do you get any console errors? Can you see what AJAX requests the browser makes upon clicking the button and what response are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4midori -

I just logged in and went to Update Indexes.  I got all of the progress bars and all of them updated just fine.  They're now showing up in the sidebar.

Is everything working for you now?

Comment: Looks like a problem with Chrome 25 on Win 7 - I see no progress bars there. Firefox works.

Comment: I do all of my testing with Chrome on OSX.  I still have the details, so let me test with my Windows 7 machine.  Update shortly.

Comment: Ok - I can't reproduce this on your site: Chrome is v25.0..1364152 m - though it says updating right now as well.  Windows 7. https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8jqy2jxbhuqx3k/4midori.png Are you running any particular browser extensions that may be part of the issue?

Comment: Weird. The only browser extension is 1password. I guess it's unique to my machine.

Comment: Do you have another machine you can test on?  I tested on Windows and Mac, both Chrome here. But I'd be curious if you can reproduce it.  I want to help figure this out, but not being able to reproduce it makes it quite difficult. :(

Comment: Unfortunately not, I don't have another Win7 machine. It may resolve itself with a future update of Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, Chrome is also barfing on the main Assets page, not finding anything. We can run a screenshare next week - please email me at bas(-at)versastudio.com to schedule a time.

Comment: And it barfs when trying to insert images in WYGWAM. Definitely something fishy.

Comment: 4midori, Win8 / 25.0.1364.160 m Chrome here - everything works as expected (including WYGWAM). Can you try disabling all your Chrome extensions?

Also, what is the response you're getting from server for AJAX requests in the console?

Comment: I turned off Chrome extensions. Console says:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tablesorter' compressed.js:39
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://kontera.com/. Origin http://www.kontera.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (program):1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined assets.min.js:8

Answer (score 1):

4midori -

Can you please check that /system/expressionengine/cache and its subfolders are 777 permissions? We see this most often when permissions are off.

Also, if you're using local folders, please make sure you also synchronize them in Content -> File Manager -> File Upload Preferences before attempting to Update Indexes.

Comment: I did both, but still getting this behavior.

Comment: Are you using relative paths for your file upload preferences? Can you post an example path for those? Thanks!  Also, is this with local folders or S3?  And lastly... I saw an Assets issue resolved by upgrading EE to 2.5.5 - so it's definitely worth doing that as part of troubleshooting.

Comment: I'll try EE2.5.5 first.

Comment: Updated to EE 2.5.5. Local folders only. Example path:
/var/www/html/kontera.com/assets/uploads/about/ and /assets/uploads/about/

Comment: Alright - any chance you'd be able to share FTP and Super Admin details for some direct troubleshooting? If so, please email them to support@pixelandtonic.com and reference this thread.  We'll make sure to come back and update after figuring this one out. :)

Comment: Sent. They expire in one hour.

Comment: I haven't yet received them - but also was out at lunch. :)  Can you re-send them and give me 24 hours to look, please?  Thanks!

Comment: The credentials don't expire - but link to them does, for security. Please email when you're ready to receive.

Comment: Hey 4midori - I never received the email at all.  I'll be around this morning for the next 3 hours or so at least checking email consistently, so now would be a great time.

Comment: I've emailed support@pixelandtonic.com twice, no response. Could you email me at bas(-AT-)versastudio.com please?

Comment: Hey 4midori - I've not received those. Just sent you an email. Can you let me know if you respond so we can make sure this works?

Comment: I did not receive an email from you, nothing in spam filter. Try versastudiollc(-at-)gmail.com instead.

Comment: Hey 4midori - let's try without my system.   Can you try lisa@pixelandtonic.com?  Thanks!